# Bootstrap datepicker date format

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

How can we format date as "Friday May 13th, 2016" in `bootstrap` datepicker ?

format: 'DD M dd, yyyy' ##produces Friday May 13, 2016

Comment: There's no datepicker in Twitter Bootstrap, therefore I assume, you use some jQuery plugin,do you?

Comment: Have you checked the plugin's event methods that you can subscribe to and call your custom function to complete that task?
e.g OnDateChanged and based on certain rules either put 5th, 1st, 2nd,etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: "dddd MMM Do, YYYY"
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0Ltv25o8/2755/