# how to get the month name instead of month no. in month picker using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

hi i am using monthpicker using bootstrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/k5zookLt/602/

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Second check out:</label>
<input type="text" style="width:25%" class="form-control form-control-2 input-sm to" placeholder="Calender">
</div>
```

it gives me the output with the month number like 02/2017, but i need the month name like (February/2017) instead of month number. Please Help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap datepicker date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37203934/bootstrap-datepicker-date-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your date format to: `format: 'MM/yyyy'`

notes: use uppercase M instead of lowercase m

Comment: if it works for you, maybe you can accept my answer? thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$('.to').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
    format: 'mm/yyyy'
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
```

To

```
$('.to').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
    format: 'MM/yyyy' //Change Here
}).on('changeDate', function(selected){
```

Considering February Month as an example

1. `format: 'MM/yyyy'`: February/2017
2. `format: 'M/yyyy'`: Feb/2017
3. `format: 'mm/yyyy'`: 02/2017
4. `format: 'm/yyyy'`: 2/2017